# ADT comprehension in Java - Adding an element to a tail of an Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, abstract-data-type

Im only starting to learn about abstract data structure. Previously im able to add elements to list with a specified types. Now im learning about an abstract type, in this case `<T>`

In this case, how do i add an element?

I want to add an element in the tail of the arraylist. this is what I have done.

```
public class Q3ArrayList<T> {


    private static final int INITIAL_SIZE = 2;
    private static final double GROWTH_FACTOR = 1.5;

    T[] values = (T[]) new Object[INITIAL_SIZE];
    int elements = 0; //NUMBER OF ELEMENTS IN THE LIST

    /**
     * Add a value to the tail of the list.
     *
     * @param value The value to be added.
     */
    public void add(T value) {

    }

   public void remove(int index) {
    values[elements--] = remove(index);

}
```

Comment: im unsure how to add the element in the tail of the list. the previous trial i always get the error message `Error:(28, 23) java: incompatible types: T cannot be converted to T[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void add(T element){
values[elements++] = element;
}
```

This will add element at the end of your array, and increase the value of `elements` by one, so you can track number of elements in array.

Comment: Perhaps: `void add(T element){values[elements++] = element;}`

Comment: That worked, but can you explain to me regarding the intuition why it worked. because how come it doesnt have any `add()` function...

Comment: @YusufNing Because you don't have an object of `ArrayList`. You add elements with `add()` method to `ArrayList`, but since you have static array (fixed number of elements) you access elements with `[]` operator.

Comment: ohh yes, i get it. But how come when i try to remove an element add a specific index it wont work. I have updated the my implementation for the remove() method in the question, can you check? cheers

Comment: @YusufNing Try `public void remove(int index) {
    values[index] = null;
    elements--;
}`

Comment: yes i worked. so basically for the remove function. its just specifying an index and then setting it to "null". correct?

Comment: @YusufNing Yes, but since you are adding elements only at the end of an array it not so logical that you remove from the middle of an array, and also that will mess the last element when you reduce `elements` by one. With this implementation, you should remove elements only from the end like this:
`void remove(){
values[--elements] = null;
}`